# KDE4 memory use optimization

Tags: kde, memory-usage

Are there any good tips for optimizing KDE4 memory consumption?

It feels like a memory hog, even when I have 4GB of RAM and i5 CPU it feels heavy.

I disabled all effects but still it feels heavy and consumes twice more memory then Gnome.

Any points for optimization **of KDE4** (not Ubuntu in general)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this package:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-low-fat-settings
```

It is specifically designed to minimize ram consumption and speed up the system as much as possible.

Comment: Nice, thanks. It saved me 100MB of memory, now it is 625 against 725...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a memory issue in machine with 4 gb RAM. It is more likely to be a graphics card driver issue. What is your graphics card and your current driver? And KDE version matters, of course among other parameters like running background processes etc.

Comment: Graphics card is Intel, so it should be very well supported, also I'm talking about Ubuntu 11.04... I don't know the exact version. After all it is memory hog even in "effects-free" configuration.